# How to return entries based on Checkboxes field criteria?

Tags: plugin-development, users, elementcriteriamodel

Ok I'm building a plugin that needs to check for an id in an array and return only users that have the id in the checkbox array.

So this is what I have:

```
$user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
$user_criteria->interests = $interestId;
$users = $user_criteria->find();
```

interests is a dynamically created checkbox array which sits under the users profile. $interestId is the id I wish to look for in that array and return all users that have it.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The default Checkboxes field type stores its value to the database as a serialized PHP array. So for an entry with checkboxes "7", "12" and "32" checked, the value in the `field_interests` column is `["7","12","32"]`.

This is **not query friendly** at all, so the best solution would be to use a different field type.

But if you really want to use the checkboxes field, here's how you can query for your elements. Convert your criteria model to a [DbCommand](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand) object and add a new `WHERE` clause with a [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) condition to perform pattern matching. Include the quotes enclosing each ID in the pattern, this should make the query robust.

```
$user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);

$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($user_criteria);
$params = array(
    ':interestId' => '%"'.$interestId.'"%',
);
$query->andWhere('field_interests LIKE :interestId', $params);
$results = $query->queryAll();

$users = EntryModel::populateModels($results);
```