# Efficient way of looping through a large amount of users?

Tags: plugin-development, users, plugins

Hi I have a plugin that loops through users to find out their interests. Counts the number of interests in total for each interest and displays this in a widget on the dashboard with the interest name and amount of users with that interest. The code I have works but fails with a max execution time and only pulls out minimal results for each interest. Is there a way to do this more efficiently so the script does not timeout. This is what I have so far but I'm sure looping through 20k+ users and checking each interest field to see if the category id is in it is highly inefficient. Cheers.

```
public function getInterestRank()
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
    $criteria->group = 'interestTags';
    $category = $criteria->find();

    //Get all users
    $user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
    $users = $user_criteria->find();

    $interestArray = array();

    foreach($category as $interest)
    {
        $title = $interest['title'];
        $count = 0;

        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            if($user['interests']) {
                if(in_array($interest['id'], $user['interests']))
                {
                    $count = $count+1;
                }
            }
        }
        $interestArray[$title] = $count;
    }

    arsort($interestArray);
    return ($interestArray);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just setup a criteria model in your “categories” for-loop, prepared to query for the users related to that category. And then use the `total()` method to get the count.

```php
foreach($category as $interest) {
    $user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
    $user_criteria->relatedTo = $interest->id;
    $count = $user_criteria->total();

    $interestArray[$interest->title] = $count;
}
```

Using the `total()` method is a lot faster than `find()`, the underlaying SQL which is necessary to get the amount of rows performs better and Craft also doesn’t have to populate the Entry models with all the data.

*(Not sure why @LukePearce deleted his answer, where he basically suggested to do the same thing.)*

Comment: I re-read the question and thought it was asking for something different, I have now re-read again and realised I was correct... oops!

Comment: @carlcs thanks for the reply and I can see this would wotk normally. The only thing is we are using a dynamic checkbox field for the user interests. This is created from the categories group. So there is no related category field being used directly. Is there a way to check the dynamic checkbox field for the $interests->id in the criteria?

Comment: @Lettie nope, a checkboxes field stores an array of IDs serialized as JSON, so there's no good way to use that data in a SQL query.

Comment: @carlcs yes sorry just read your previous post http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11991/how-to-return-entries-based-on-checkboxes-field-criteria cheers